# Shared via on 22pF cap only used to smooth differential clock signal?

Tags: via, high-pass-filter

Google's so cluttered these days, it's hard to find simple answers.

I've got differential clocks running around 500MHz (1000Ms).

There's some optional 22pf caps on each Address line, going to the dram.

It's Micron's DDR2 recommended layout.

It's so crowded, I'm sorely tempted to share vias between them.

No more than 2 to a via.

And they're only 22pf.

But I sure would like to crank that clock up to 800MHz later on (1600Ms).

Could sharing a via on 22pf caps make any difference?  The vias are tiny (6 mils).

And, anyone have the common sense to know the cutoff point for sharing vias?

Like, anything under 1nF, don't worry about sharing the vias?

Answer (score 1):

lets model that.

Assume 1 nanoHenry per via.

Assume 200 picosecond edge.

assume 1 volt swing (your voltage may vary).

The current thru 50 pF(both caps), with 1volt in 200 picoseconds, will be

I = C * dV/dT

I = 50pF * 1v/0.2 nanoseconds = 50/0.2 * pico * 1/nano = 250e-3 = 0.25 amps
assuming PCB foil inductance dies not limit current.

The rise and fall times of this current will be 1/2 of the voltage, or 100PS.

The voltage across the inductor (the GND upset) will be V = L * dI/dT

V = 1nH * 0.25 amps / 0.1 nanosecond = 2.5 volt.

So there will be lots of crosstalk; the gnd side of the shared caps, which is the top of the via, will be 2.5 volt.

......................................

Another way to think is : what is reactance of 22pf ( or 50pf) at 2,000MHz?

since 1pf at 1,000MHz is 159 ohms, we know 22pF at 2GHz is 159/44 = 4 ohms.

While the 1nH inductor to ground is 12 ohms (2 * 2 * pi).

Thus we are guaranteed massive trace-trace crosstalk at 2,000MHz,

Comment: Dang.  You answered it, but I sure don't like the answer.